# Rails shows rows from model, which aren't created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, pg

I have this part of code:

```
<% current_user.meta_accounts.each do |meta_account| %>
    <%= content_tag(:li, link_to(meta_account.name, 'javascript:void(0)')) %>
<% end %>
```

So, I want Rails to show all my `MetaAccount`s in list, but I get this:

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Wallet</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Credit card</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Debit card</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Debts</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">javascript:void(0)</a></li> #This is the problem
```

So, it also shows me `MetaAccount`, which isn't created yet.

In my MetaAccounts table I have this. I'm using Postgres.

[image]

So, it also shows me the last row, where row_number is `*`. I don't know why, and how to avoid this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<% current_user.meta_accounts.select(&:persisted?).each do |meta_account| %>
  <%= content_tag(:li, link_to(meta_account.name, 'javascript:void(0)')) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Guess we answered around the same time. Will delete mine since OP accepted your version.

Answer (score 1):

The * row you see in PostgreSQL is not an actual record, it's just a quick way to create new records. If you want to be sure, run the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MetaAccounts WHERE user_id=1
```

It will return 4.

I think the problem comes from an unsaved `MetaAccount` object in `current_user.meta_accounts`. This could be the case for instance in a form, where you build an empty object bound to the form. Make sure you don't have a call to `current_user.meta_accounts.build(...)`.

If so, you can simply skip in your `each` loop all `MetaAccount` objects with a blank `name`.

Comment: In my `meta_accounts_controller` I'm using this:
`def create
    @meta_account = current_user.meta_accounts.build(params[:meta_account])` There're no MetaAccount `build` in other parts of my app.

Comment: But `current_user.meta_accounts.where('user_id = ?', current_user.id).each` helped. Thanks!